# no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'int')

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operators

Given the following code;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int number_1 = 3;
    int result_1 = 10;
    result_1 += number_1;
    cout << ++result_1;
    cout << result_1 += number_1;
}
```

The line `cout << result_1 += number_1;` giving me an error.

> no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream' and 'int')

On the other hand, the `cout << ++result_1;` is running without any problems.

Can anyone please explain what is the error is for, what the cause is?

Comment: `cout << result_1` returns the `cout` object. That object doesn't have a `+=` overload for ints.

Comment: Also, it is generally not that good an idea to mix computations with output. If you compute all the values first and perform the output later, that most often results in clearer code with fewer bugs. (And you have just found one of those :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Can anyone please explain what is the error is for, what the cause is?

According to [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator<<` has higher precedence than `operator+=`, so your code is equivalent as:

```
(cout << result_1) += number_1;
```

while `cout << result_1` will return `std::cout` (i.e. `std::ostream&`) and then `operator+=` is attempted to be called on `std::ostream` and it doesn't exist. That's what the error message trying to tell you.

You could change it to:

```
cout << (result_1 += number_1) ;
```

or avoid such kind of confusing code fundamentally.

```
result_1 += number_1;
cout << result_1;
```

> 2. On the other hand `cout << ++result_1;` is running with out any problem.

Beasuse `operator++` has higher precedence than `operator<<`. So it's equivalent as `cout << (++result_1);` and would be fine.

Comment: Actually you "should" not do this at all

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the operator precedence rules, you'll find that the statement is equivalent to

```
(cout << result_1) += number_1 ;
```

The `operator<<` returns the `std::cout`. And there exists no `std::ostream::operator+=(int)`.

Solution: Use parenthesis to express the intended order of operations.

> On the other hand cout << ++result_1; is running with out any problem

As one would expect. Study the precedence of operators.

Answer (score 2):

*Operator precedence*.

The call is semantically equivalent to something like `cout << result_1; cout += result;` - which is invalid.

Adding parentheses to the code (allowing the `+=` computed before the `<<`) as follows allows the code to compile;

```
cout << (result_1 += number_1);
```

---

On the error itself; the compiler cannot find an implementation of the `operator +=` for the arguments provided - there isn't a standard one. This is because the `cout << result_1` is evaluated before the `operator +=`. From the above, this makes sense, but doesn't immediately indicate where the potential fix can be applied.

Answer (score 2):

Read you commpiler error carefully. Everything is there :) .

The reason for error is operator precedence.
Compiler first executes `cout << result_1`.
Then, it tries to execute something like this: `cout += number_1`.

Does it have any sense?

To do what you intended change your line:

```
cout << (result_1 += number_1);
```

I strongly recommend reading this:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence